# Third-party scripts after page speed is very slow in Next js

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I added third-party scripts like Statcounter, Zoom Chat, and Google Tag Manager. After the implementation of these scripts. page speed is going slow down.
Please let me know if anybody has any suggestions.

```
`<script
      strategy="lazyOnload"
      type="text/javascript"
      data-cfasync="false"
      dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: gtmScriptFun }}
    />
    <script
        id="statcounter"
        type="text/javascript"
        src="https://www.statcounter.com/counter/counter.js"
        async
        strategy="lazyOnload"
      />`
```